# Facebook authentication whithout reloading or refreshing page by angularjs

Tags: angularjs, facebook

How do I login via facebook without reloading Or refreshing the page in angularjs application ?

Answer (score 0):

With the JavaScript SDK, and `FB.login`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Something specific for AngularJS: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/angularjs

Here is a tutorial, if the Facebook docs are not good enough for you: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/